# How to speed up transition in phonegap application?

Tags: jquery, cordova, transition

In my phonegap application, I have a lot of images, audio and animations using also list of images. I am using parallax.js to make some parallel plans.
The transition should be after swiping.

I tried to set the application as multiple pages html, but the time of transition was too slow. I tried also to set my application in one page html and I placed the pages in DIVs but still have the same problem.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html (Effects->Transitions, scroll by clicking)

Also

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/transitions/

Comment: The question is: is there anyway to speed the time of loading pages?

Comment: If you are using a single html page and views with dojo mobile, it's fast. While using several pages with jquery mobile within a single html page is also fast.

Comment: Do you think dojo is faster than setting views in DIV and animating transitions using css and jquery?

Comment: I don't know. Try it and make your own opinion

Comment: Thank you so much, but I need to use multiple html files and I need to minimize the loading time of each one because they are heavy :( what should I do